# Non-Static field in Object

Tags: static, kotlin

I have a Kotlin object class. I want certain fields of this class to not be static. In Java, I would add static to everything that needs to be static. Can one do this with an object class or must I create a regular class with a companion object?

Something like this:

```
object TestObject {
    val static1: Int = 10
    val static2: Int = 20
    notstatic val notstatic1 = 13
}
```

Comment: use a companion object or an object class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `static` keyword in Kotlin. The only way to make something `static` is to use the `@JvmStatic` annotation:

```
object Foo {

    @JvmStatic
    val someVal: String = "foo"

}
```

An `object` is an object, not a `class`. If you want to use class properties use a `class` and add a `companion object` to it:

```
class Foo {

    val nonStatic: String = "foo"

    companion object {

        // not actual static but accessible by Foo.static
        val static: String = "bar"
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay, if there is no way, i'll have to use companion object. Thanks for the quick reply!